# Why null-coalescing operator (??) in a mathematical function works different without parenthesis?

Tags: function, c#-3.0, null-coalescing-operator

Hello i have a doubt about this mathematical function in C# and i want to know why this happens.
This two lines give different results, why?

```
container.price * (1 + (container.tax_rate / 100m)) * (1 - (container.promotion_rate ?? 0 / 100m))
```

Returns -> -839.9944

```
container.price * (1 + (container.tax_rate / 100m)) * (1 - ((container.promotion_rate ?? 0) / 100m))
```

Returns -> 50.99966

And the only difference in the function is the parenthesis on the second function: `(container.promotion_rate ?? 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null-coalescing operator has a lower precedence than the divide operator. Therefore, your code is interpreted as

```
 container.promotion_rate ?? (0 / 100m)
```

which gives you a different result.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`/` has a higher precedence than `??`.

Your first expression is parsed as `container.promotion_rate ?? (0 / 100m)`